# android studio attributes layout margin disappear

Tags: android-studio, attributes, margin

I am using Android-Studio and lately I ran into some situation.

till now I was using the attributes window for set the margin layout (to top/left/right/bottom) but in some point of time, Probably last week, this margin option dissapir. how can i return it?
(i know i can do this at the xml text file but its More comfortable at the design option)

my attribute look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmdkl.jpg)

this is how i want it to look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogdhB.jpg)

Comment: Did you try to add individual constraints by clicking on the imageView in the blueprint, then by clicking on the circles that (should) appear in the middle of each side?

Comment: Maybe you are not using constraint layout

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem today and this is how I solved it.

select 'Floating mode' on options that comes up when you click on 'cog' in attributes window. now, margins will come back.

if you don't want floating anymore, attach it back to right side and margins will stay now.

It seems like a bug in Android studio that margins disappear for no reason.

Comment: For me it didn't come back when selecing Floating mode, but when I docked it again, it was back.